# Multiple IP address in a machine

Tags: ip-address, opennebula

I am running an opennebula instance with opensuse as a guest machine. There is only one network interface eth0 with ipaddress 192.168.122.155 . However I can ping the machine 2 IP address 192.168.122.155 and 192.168.122.160. I dont want to assign 192.168.122.160 to the vm. How can I figure out what is going on?

Comment: If you didn't explicitly set .160 to the VM, it sounds like you have bridged your virtual network, and the VM has picked up a DHCP address.

Comment: Can you explain the setup you'd like to have?

Comment: Yes the virtual netowrk is bridged. How do I check if it has obtained the address from DHCP?

Comment: Thanks I checked the /var/log/messages and it seems vm obtained address from dhcp.  eth0: renewing lease of 192.168.122.160. But ifconfig still shows .155 then why am I able to ping .160?

Comment: It would seem that if the connection is bridged, and you have DHCP, the server has obtained .155, and the VM obtained .160. You can ping both addresses because there is one machine on each... if you don't want the VM to have an IP, configure it to **not** lease from DHCP.

Comment: can you provide ifconfig -a output from the VM?

Answer (score 1):

192.168.122/24 is a common subnet used for the VM Host's NAT'd network. Perhaps you're pinging one of the other guests?

Comment: Not really. I tried ssh-ing to the machine and it is the same one.

Comment: If you already know that, such information really ought to be included in the initial question.